# MEAN stack: Is it necessary to run two servers for a mean stack app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am making a MEAN stack app. MEAN(MongoDB, ExpressJs, Angular 6, NodeJs).

I am confused that will there be two servers used to run the app.(we have to run two servers simultaneously)

for back-end(Node) `http://localhost:3000` and
for front-end(Angular) `http://localhost:4200`.

and if not then how to run the app?

Comment: Who told you that you have to offer two services on some obscure ports? And *one server (software) thread* can open *multiple ports*

Comment: That's a best practice to leverage load balancers for high availability and decouple components to avoid a mix of responsibilities.  However, you can run all on a single server (Weird and ugly).

Comment: `Node.js` is the server, `ExpressJS` is a router that routes whatever URL you type into your URL bar and displays a page that you specified via (POST/GET) request e.g. Angular.

Comment: Read [`Understanding The MEAN Stack`](https://www.codingdojo.com/blog/understanding-mean-stack/). It's short and to the point.

Comment: @ele "best practice" well if you got so many requests that you need multiple nodejs servers yes ... but i don't think that a newbie will hit such workloads ...

Comment: @JonasW. yeah, but the OP needs to understand that for future challenges.

Comment: Not to mention, when you spread components that rely on each other across multiple servers, you're increasing the points of failure.  There's no reason to do this unless one server can't handle the load.

Comment: Just build your angular app and use the dist folder in node js to run your app on single server.

Comment: To make it simple and keep it short : you have 3 servers : API (NodeJS), database (Mongo), SPA (Angular). You can shorten it to two : API + SPA, and database. But you can't go under that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we have to run two servers simultaneously

Yes. At least one database server (MongoDB) and one webserver (NodeJS).

> for back-end(Node) http://localhost:3000 and for front-end(Angular) http://localhost:4200.

Not really. The mongodb server will start on an internal port (27017 by default) and the webserver should answer requests via port 80 (and / or 443 if you want TLs). For testing you can assign other ports for sure but if you want to go in production, ports 3000 and 4200 are nonsense. But these ports are not opened by different servers, just by the webserver. And there is no "frontend port" ...

Answer (score 0):

In development you run two apps, but for the production not. 
Normally you build the front-end app (in this case Angular 6) so you have just static assets (JS, HTML, etc.) and you serve this simply via web server. The Express app have to run separately, possibly using reverse-proxy set up on the web server.

Comment: You'll be forced to run two servers if you have a database. See @Jonas' answer, which explains is greatly.

Comment: i'm talking about application servers (as i assume also the question was targeted towards this problematic), it's quite obvious that you need a database server as well for mongo...

Comment: Don't assume, correct his statement instead, it teaches him vocabulary ! And `The Express app have to run separately` isn't true either, you can totally run an Express application that serves both your API and your SPA.

Comment: @trichetriche c'mon, i'm not here to play word games :) of course it can serve both API and SPA, but then it still needs to be running separately from the web server and you have 1 application server running.. as i said..

Comment: No, you're here to help, but anway that's not the point. The webserver and the application server are the same, so I don't get your point there.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) which will mean you only need one server.